# How to run batch-file from network-share?

Tags: batch-file, autoit, execution, network-share

I have a batch-file located on a network-share `\\mydirector\somefoldername\otherfolder\mybatch.bat`.
I am looking for AutoIt to run this batch-file.

The following code does not work:

```
Run ('\\mydirector\somefoldername\otherfolder\mybatch.bat')
```

How to run a batch-file from a network-share?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with working directory specified:

```
RunWait ( @ComSpec & " /c \\mydirector\somefoldername\otherfolder\mybatch.bat", "\\mydirector\somefoldername\otherfolder")
```

Meaning:

```
/C           Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
@ComSpec     points to cmd.exe
```